# SQL Server deadlock condition not being reported back to client

Tags: sql-server

We recently converted an app from OLEDB to ODBC for security reasons.  As of the conversion, however, a deadlock condition easily observed in SQL Trace is not being reported back to the client.  I observe the call to SQLExecute returning NO_DATA instead.  There is an insert trigger involved in the transaction, and the deadlock occurs on one of the updates performed within the trigger.  Can anyone suggest why the deadlock condition is being masked?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been a while since I coded with MS stack, but I remember that ODBC connections have some configuration paramenters, MAYBE one of those is the error handling?

Comment: Does the trigger do `SET NOCOUNT ON`? (If not, it should.) What happens when you call `SQLMoreResults`?

Comment: Also just a note that the SQL Server OleDB Provider is being un-deprecated, and a new release is planned for Q1 2018:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/

Comment: Re:  Does the trigger do SET NOCOUNT ON? (If not, it should.) No, it does not, and I had already wondered if that was the issue.  However, I hoped to get some guidance on how not having that could cause the deadlock to be masked.

Comment: We just spent months converting from OLEDB to ODBC, so I doubt that returning to OLEDB is an option.

Comment: I don't write ODBC applications myself, but I've had multiple experiences with third-party applications misinterpreting the row count of the result set (which is returned when `NOCOUNT` is `OFF`) as the actual result of the query without looking further. If your trigger executes a command that does not end in error and returns no results, the `0` row count will end up back on the client. If the next statement produces an error, that error is not actually processed by the client until it asks for the *next* result. If it never does, it gets no error. At least, that's how I *think* it works.

Comment: Re: NOCOUNT and result:  The app is running multiple threads, each of which is doing inserts into a table.  The insert trigger on that table executes an update statement against a much smaller table using a key value that will keep the updates unique for each thread.  My theory is that the deadlock occurs because of SQL Server lock escalation.  That would not be a case of the trigger executing a command without an error.  However, I will modify the trigger to include SET NOCOUNT ON (if only because it is best practice) and see if the problem persists after that change.  Thanks to all.